# How to read MBR data on windows system

Tags: c++, windows, mbr

I'm using a file that has MBR code at an offset of 54 bytes.
In the main() function, I'm calling OpenMBbrFile(), then ReadMbrData(). 
However, I'm not able to read MBR in my Buffer Properly. Please Help Me with the Issue..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
BOOL OpenMbrFile(LPWSTR sPath)
{

    cout << "OpenMBR: Create Handle" << endl;

    m_hMbrFile = CreateFile(sPath
        , GENERIC_READ
        , FILE_SHARE_READ
        , NULL
        , OPEN_EXISTING
        , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
        , NULL);

    if (m_hMbrFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CloseMbrFile()
{

    cout << "CloseMBR: Closing Handle" << endl;

    BOOL bReturn = TRUE;

    if (m_hMbrFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        bReturn = CloseHandle(m_hMbrFile);

    m_hMbrFile = NULL;

    cout << "Returning from CloseMBR" << endl;

    return bReturn;
}


BOOL ReadMbrData()
{

    cout << "ReadMBR: Initialization" << endl;

    BOOL bReturn = FALSE;
    DWORD dwByteRead = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER filepointer;
    filepointer.QuadPart = 54;  //MBR data in File at offset 54
    BYTE* pBuff = NULL;
    pBuff = new BYTE[512];
    if (!pBuff) 
    {
        cout << "ReadMBR: Cleaning Stuff up" << endl;
        if (pBuff) delete[] pBuff;
        CloseMbrFile();
        ClosePhysicalDrive();
        return bReturn;
    }

    if (m_hMbrFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return FALSE;

    cout << "ReadMBR: Setting fp" << endl;

    if(!SetFilePointerEx(m_hMbrFile, filepointer, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    {
        cout << "Failed to SetFilePointer ( " << m_hMbrFile << ", " << filepointer.QuadPart << ", 0, FILE_BEGIN)" << endl;
        cout << "ReadMBR: Cleaning Stuff up" << endl;
        if (pBuff) delete[] pBuff;
        CloseMbrFile();
        ClosePhysicalDrive();
        return bReturn;

    }

    cout << "ReadMBR: Starting to read File" << endl;

    bReturn = ReadFile(m_hMbrFile, pBuff, sizeof(*pBuff), &dwByteRead, 0);

    if (bReturn)
        bReturn = (sizeof(*pBuff) == dwByteRead);       //Need to check this condition? shd it be 512 or size of wud do??

    cout << "ReadMBR: Cleaning Stuff up" << endl;
    if (pBuff) delete[] pBuff;
    CloseMbrFile();
    ClosePhysicalDrive();

    return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: What did you pass to `OpenMbrFile` as `sPath`?

Comment: While calling OpenMbrFile, I called it with sPath as argument and sPath was of the datatype LPWSTR

Comment: And what was the value?

Comment: Filepath for the MBR File which I wanted to read.

Comment: So what was the result? Did `OpenMbrFile` return false? Did `GetLastError` give you an error code? Which one?

Comment: I'm getting garbage value in my buffer which doesn't contain MBR data also the value of dwByteRead is 1. So, It's not reading the complete thing. Is something wrong with the buffer Initialization? I haven't tried GetLastError!